# Usage of powerShell.AddCommand

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like to execute this event using c#.

> Get-WinEvent -Path 'D:\Events\myevents.evt' -Oldest | Select-Object
>   -Property * | ForEach-Object {$_ | ConvertTo-Json}

I have written upto

```
 path = "D:\\Events\\myevents.evt";  
 var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
 powerShell.AddCommand("Get-WinEvent");
 powerShell.AddParameter("Path");
 powerShell.AddArgument(path);
 powerShell.AddParameter("Oldest");
 powerShell.AddCommand("Select-Object");
 powerShell.AddParameter("Property");
 powerShell.AddArgument("*");
```

I am stuck on writing for ForEach-Object {$_ | ConvertTo-Json}. Let me know how to proceed.

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 6):

Keith's answer is totally valid if `Path` come from trusted source.
Otherwise, it can be vulnerable for script injection. (demo https://gist.github.com/vors/528faab6411db74869d4)

I suggest a compromised solution:
wrap you script in a function, which takes dynamic arguments and `Invoke` it with `AddScript()`. Now you have a function in your powershell runspace/session. You can call this function with `AddCommand()` + `AddParameter()`. Remember, that you need to call `powershell.Commands.Clear()` after first `Invoke`, otherwise commands will be piped.

Code can look like that:

```
const string script = @"function wrapper($path) {return (Get-WinEvent -Path $path -Oldest | Select-Object -Property * | ForEach-Object {$_ | ConvertTo-Json}) }";
ps.AddScript(script);
ps.Invoke();
ps.Commands.Clear();
ps.AddCommand("wrapper").AddParameter("path", path);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the `AddScript` method:

```
powershell.AddScript("Get-WinEvent D:\Events\myevents.evt -Oldest | ConvertTo-Json");
```

I think you could also simplify that script and pipe directly to ConvertTo-Json.

Comment: But I would like to have "path" to be dynamic.

Comment: `powershell.AddScript(String.Format("Get-WinEvent '{0}' ...", path));`

Comment: @KeithHill then you need to worry about script-injections, if path can come from the outside of author's code.