# Powershell Invoke() returns empty if I use AddParameter

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2007

I have a C# script to mail-enable a distribution group in Exchange. I have tried the following code, which works currently:

```
Command command = new Command("Enable-DistributionGroup -Identity '#Test DL'");
psInstance.Commands.AddCommand(command);
```

The above code works, and will return a string with the name of the distribution group. Upon checking the distribution group, it has become mail-enabled.

The below code does not work, and returns an empty string:

```
Command command = new Command("Enable-DistributionGroup").AddParameter("Identity", "#Test DL");
psInstance.Commands.AddCommand(command);
```

Am I using the AddParameter function incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the command object, and then do a `command.AddParameter` separately.  See the C# example at [PowerShell.AddParameter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182434(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can also reference [Usage of powerShell.AddCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627192/usage-of-powershell-addcommand) for an example from another SO poster.

Comment: I have also tried the following but to no avail:  
`Command command = new Command("Enable-DistributionGroup");`  
  
`command.addParameter("Identity", "#Test DL");`  
  
`psInstance.Commands.AddCommand(command);`