# C# application with Powershell host

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

The problem is about sending command to Powershell,

My C# application sends commands one by one in order to get right directory to execute some files but even I downloaded all the necessary packages application throws an error

> 

```
An exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException' in 'cd C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\pathToFileforExecute\\ ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

> 

My NuGet Packages ;
[image]

My code is like

```
ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted");
                ps.Invoke();
                ps.AddCommand("cd C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\pathToFileforExecute\\");
                ps.AddCommand("./executeTheFile");
                ps.AddCommand("pwd");
                Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
```

Please help me to solve problem I found this feed but it didn't work for me https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8119

I tried deleting the System.Management.Automation because I read this package shouldn't use by itself.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. It looks like you are trying to ask a new question. Please use the "Ask question" button, and do not edit your existing question. The given answers and comments only match your original question. Also the question might be useful to someone else, however by editing it away, you make it unaccessible for search engines.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Yes I am trying desperately to ask a question but the system is blocking. I am just a learner.

Comment: Please see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). If you are unable to find an answer why the system doesn't let you ask questions there, you can try to create a question on Stack Overflow Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `AddCommand` without the `AddParameter` option. The path is a parameter.

Try the following code:

```
ps.AddCommand("Set-Location").AddParameter("Path", C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\pathToFileforExecute\\);
```

Or you may use the `AddScript` method instead of `AddCommand` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627372/761095).

Note that the `cd` command is an alias for `Set-Location` in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for answer it worked ! I have been trying for 2 days to solve the problem. How can I execute the executable file with PS './' is not working like execute from PS shell ?

Comment: @SanberkKüçükkelepçe Try the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet and provide the path to the executable as a parameter.

Comment: BTW, why do you even need to use PowerShell from C#? You have C# at your hands. You could start the executable without using PowerShell (e.g., see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9679375/761095)

Comment: Is there way to use this format in PS './someFile.exe' ?

Comment: Okay I found it,  "-NoNewWindow" .  Thanks a lot

Comment: because I need to use ADB(AndroidDataBridge) in order to used this command I need to have interactive shell